# When I navigate a new screen on Android, the position of the previous screen moves slightly up

Tags: react-native, jsx

My stack navigation structure is:

```
<NavigationContainer>
        <DummyStackNavigation.Navigator mode="modal">
        <DummyStackNavigation.Screen name="MainNavigation" component={MainNavigation} options={{ headerShown: false }}/>
        <DummyStackNavigation.Screen name="Comment" component={Comment} options={{ headerShown: false , cardStyle:{ backgroundColor: "transparent" }}} />
    </DummyStackNavigation.Navigator>
</NavigationContainer>
```

When I navigate to "Comment" screen on Android, the position of the "MainNavigation" screen moves slightly up. this doesn't happen on iOS.

Can't I fix the position of "MainNavigation" scrren?